# How to give AT commands to HM-10 using hardware RX/TX pins of arduino uno?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I have been successful in using **`SoftwareSerial`** to pass AT commands to an HM-10 module. But, I want to use Hardware Rx/Tx pins (Digital pins 0/1) to do the same. Is there any library available for this purpose? Or, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hardware serial, but I advise you not to.
Rx/Tx pins are shared with USB to serial, so you cannot use the serial-monitor or upload to the Arduino without disconnecting your HM10.